# How can I logout from facebook from my app in MonoTouch

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin.ios, logout

I am using Facebook integration in my application. I am logging with Facebook and now I want logout from my application. Many members are asked this question but I am not getting proper solution.

Comment: Are you using iOS 6 Facebook integration?  Or the Facebook SDK?

Comment: I am using iOS 6 Facebook integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add these 4 lines of codes to logout button, to clear all the cookies, so that you can successfully logout from facebook.

```
    NSHttpCookieStorage storage = NSHttpCookieStorage.SharedStorage;

    foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies) 
    {
      if(cookie.Domain == ".facebook.com")
      {
        storage.DeleteCookie(cookie);
      }

    }
```

Comment: hi i am using this i am getting this error .."interface statically allocated"  Please Help me @Dorababu Dodda

Comment: check this also http://pastie.org/5492534     did not solve my problem with both of those codes  Please Guide me  @Dorababu Dodda

Comment: in if condition compare cookie.domain == ".facebook.com"              like as in my code.

Comment: yes. i did like that.. if i am doing like i am geting this error in this line "foreach (NSHttpCookie cookie in storage.Cookies)"  says use of undeclared identifier "NSHttpCookie".  i changed "NSHttpCookie"  to "NSHTTPCookie"  then it says errors as "unexpected interface name" NSHTTPCookie expected expression  @Dorababu Dodda

Comment: then declare NSHttpCookie cookie;                                  and call in foreach like this                                                                                      foreach(cookie in storage.Cookies)

Answer (score 0):

The Social.framework, provided with Apple iOS 6, does not require you to login, nor to logout.

The user credentials (for Facebook) are kept in the iOS settings (out of reach of the applications) so the operating system is able to log you in *on demand* and will log you out when you're finished. That likely occurs after you release your last instance of `SLRequest` or some time afterward (e.g. caching).

Comment: Ok but when I logout from my app the application is closing and again when I am logging from Facebook then the Facebook not asking my credentials it is directly entering to my app. This is happening. Regards.